# for loop with dynamic variable

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop

```
for ($x = 1; $x<=4 ; $x++) { for ($y = 1; $y<=6 ; $y++){

$query=mysql_query("COUNT QUERY as X")

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)

$A10$x$y = row['X'];

}}
```

basically for loops gives 1-1 1-2....4-4 4-5 4-6
My question is i want the result of the query 
to be placed in a dynamic variable

```
$A1011= result1; $A1012= result2; $A1013= result3;
```

and so on...

So i can call the variable for displays

Comment: You should try not to put queries within loops. It's bad practice and will make for extremely slow performance with lots of data. We're talking possible time-outs here with only 4500 of those.

Comment: im just counting data and its faster than getting one by one and then count++ on if loops

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 dimensional array to store the result. example:

```
$A10 = array();
for ($x = 1; $x<=4 ; $x++) { for ($y = 1; $y<=6 ; $y++){

$query=mysql_query("COUNT QUERY as X")

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)

$A10[i][j] = row['X'];

}}
echo A10[1][3];
```

Comment: so outside the loop i can call him

Comment: echo $A11.'TOTAL';

Comment: You should declare the array before starting of the loop. You can call it outside of the loop and get the data stored inside of the array.

Comment: it says Undefined variable: A1011 <-- this one is generated in the loop

Comment: Mark as an answer if it helped you. :)